Auto-logout after elapsed time
I'm attempting to make my page auto navigate to the login page if they user's cookie has expired.  I'm using javascript on the page, to check at an interval and middleware to check if the user is authenticated.  This doesn't seem to be working.  I'm assuming it's becuase it's still sliding the expiration of the cookie.  How can I check the cookie to see if that's the issue and not slide it on this call?
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

app.UseMiddleware<SessionExpiryCheckMiddleware>();



public class SessionExpiryCheckMiddleware
 {
     private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

     public SessionExpiryCheckMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
     {
         _next = next;
     }

     public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
     {
         // Only check session for specific paths
         if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/SessionStatus"))
         {
             var isAuthenticated = context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

             // If user is authenticated, proceed without extending session
             if (!isAuthenticated)
             {
                 // Invalidate session
                 context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                 return;
             }
         }

         await _next(context);
     }
 }

setInterval(function () {
    fetch('/SessionStatus', {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.status);
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // Session has expired, redirect to login page
                window.location.href = '/Identity/Account/Login';
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error checking session status:', error);
        });
}, 5000);


You can check the expiration time of the cookie in the browser's developer tools to determine whether the sliding expiration is configured correctly.

I've tried the developer tools to look at the experiation date and it shows session

In order to do that, you need to create endpoint to logout:
[HttpPost("logout")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    return Ok();
}

And then call it from your front end JavaScript code.
Reference: AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync Method

The problem with this is that the middleware is always returning a status 200

@user568551 MIddleware? What middleware? And what it should do instead? and why?

Middleware was my attempt to intercept the request without sliding the expiration of the cookie.

Since you're working with cookies, the browser will automatically remove a cookie when it has expired. To redirect a user to the login page you can use the CookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath property.
You can read more about it in the documentation.
When a call is made to a protected endpoint without the proper authorization, the API will return a 302 redirection status code to the specified LoginPath. It sounds like this would cover exactly what you want to implement.
You can configure the LoginPath like so:
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "Route to your login page";
});

This removes the need to implement both custom middleware and a timer that verifies if the cookie is still valid and then redirects if needed.
Edit:
Since you want your front-end to redirect the user after cookie has expired even though the user is not actively interacting with the page.
You could implement a simple protected endpoint that you can hit to check if the user is still authorized.
Can be as simple as:
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("isAuthenticated")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateAuthentication()
{
    return Ok();
}

Since this endpoint requires authorization to be accessed the framework will automatically check if the user is still authenticated. If not it will automatically return a 302 redirection response, otherwise it will simply respond with a 200 Ok
Now you can create a global timer, of a little over 5 minutes, in your front end that resets after every call to your API. When the timer reaches the end, the isAuthenticated endpoints will be called and the user will get redirected to the login page.
This way you ensure the user gets redirected to the login page without accidentally sliding the cookie expiration automatically.
I hope this helps!

I already have the options.LoginPath.  It the cookie expires and I click on a link it does redirect to the login page, but if it's just sitting there, it does not autoredirect.  That's what I'm going for with the javascript and middleware.

Well in that case you could just create a simple protected endpoint, E.g. IsAuthenticated that you can call in the timer. If the users' cookie expired the LoginPath will automatically redirect the user. No need for custom middleware. I updated my answer to include this.

When that endpoint is called though, the cookies expiration slides and it never expires

Ah, I see. Well, then you'll have to create some kind of global countdown, in your case a little over 5 minutes, that resets after every call to your API. This would ensure the cookie won't automatically slide and the user gets redirected after the timer called the isAuthenticated endpoint I suggested.

Here is a method you can refer to
Since when setting the cookie at the Session level, the cookie will automatically expire after the user closes the browser.
Therefore, you can try to persist the cookie,
CookieIsPersistent = true, and set its sliding expiration time such as
options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
When we log in, we can see the expiration time of the cookie:

Then detect the expiration on the front end and redirect the page:
<script>
      setInterval(function () {
         
          fetch('/api/check-session', {
              method: 'GET',
              credentials: 'same-origin'
          }).then(response => {
              console.log(response);
              if (response.redirected) {
                  window.location.href = '/Account/Login';
              }
          });
      }, 23000);  
  </script>



[Authorize]
 [HttpGet("/api/check-session")]
 public IActionResult CheckSession()
 {
     
     return Ok();
 }

When the cookie expires, it will redirect to my login page:

